# To what extent will results change when fitting random forest structurally vs in batch?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am facing a problem where I am not sure how to apply the random forest algorithm. Suppose my target variable is $Y$ and I have some $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_p$ as predictors. I am applying the random forest algorithm to this data set resulting in $\hat{Y}$.

I rewritten my problem and target variable to:

1. For target variable $\frac{Y}{Z}$ and predictors $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_p$. I apply a random forest to this retrieving estimated variable $\hat{\frac{Y}{Z}}$.
2. For target variable $Z$ and the same predictors $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_p$. I again apply the random forest and obtain $\hat{Z}$.

If I optimize both random forests in 1 and 2, to what extend will the result of $\hat{Z} * \hat{\frac{Y}{Z}}$ differ from $\hat{Y}$, from the first formulation? 
Which approach would be the best and is there any literature for this?

Comment: In general, using two models to predict one thing will be less efficient than using one model to predict one thing. The criterion for models 1 and 2 to be considered "good" or "optimal" is how well they predict Z and Y/Z, neither of which are your desired output.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why is this convoluted procedure necessary?

Comment: The underlying model is more classical and estimates $\hat{Z}$ and $\hat{\frac{Y}{Z}}$ seperately to obtain an estimate for $\hat{Y}$. Basically $\hat{Z}$ represents the probability of mortality for a big population and $\hat{\frac{Y}{Z}}$ the deviation from a smaller population. $\hat{Y}$ is then the probability of mortality of that smaller population. I improve the end results of the model by a multiplier estimated by a random forest. I was wondering if I should estimate that multiplier based on the end results of $\hat{Y}$ or also split into a multiplier for the two seperately.